# Haskell HList: how to lookup a value

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, hlist, heterogeneous-list

I'm using [HList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList) package and I need two functions like `(!!)` and `elem`. The first function receives an **HList** and an integer **n** and returns the **n-th element of the HList**. The second one receives an **HList** and an element and verify if that element is in the **HList** based on the **Eq** instance of that element.

Can someone help me achieve this?

Comment: What should the type of these functions be? Clearly a simple `list -> index -> element` -ish one won't do the trick, because the element type depends on the index. There are ways around this, but they all have their difficulties.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The type should be something like you mentioned, e.g, `(!!) :: HList x -> Int -> element`. The problem is what's the type of `element`?

Comment: To encourage people to provide an answer, you should provide proof that you achieve some constructive thought. Then you could point where you block :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing function for `HList` is called [`hLookupByHNat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-HList-HArray.html#v:hLookupByHNat).

You cannot simply index an `HList` by an `Int` because the type of the result depends on the index, and Haskell does not have dependent types (yet). It is possible to emulate dependent types in Haskell, hence the existence of `hLookupByHNat` as a lookup function on `HList`. But be aware that dependently-typed programming is not going to be easy, even in languages that actually support them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried **hLookupByHNat** (that represents `(!!)`) and it works fine. Do you know how to achieve the `elem` behavior?

Comment: If the list contains only one element of the same type as the one you are searching for, you can use `hMember`. In the general case, I don't see it, and you may have to implement it yourself with `hFoldr`.